# How to select multiple rows filled with constants?

Tags: sql, select, constants

Selecting constants without referring to a table is perfectly legal in an SQL statement:

```
SELECT 1, 2, 3
```

The result set that the latter returns is a single row containing the values. I was wondering if there is a way to select multiple rows at once using a constant expression, something kind of:

```
SELECT ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))
```

I would want something like the above that works and returns a result set with 3 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: Your imagined syntax above is prettier (and more consistent with INSERT INTO) than the official syntax.  Just say'in.

Comment: @PeteAlvin The imagined syntax already has a meaning in Postgres (a single row with a tuple is selected).

Comment: The sql server answer below works well for sql server, and almost matches this syntax.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269562/2129481

Answer (score 260, accepted):

```
SELECT 1, 2, 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 5, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: I used this with SQL Server and it worked, but I had to use `AS` to give aliases on the first `SELECT`

Comment: thank you @ArtB, this comment may help other developers to get correct syntax

Comment: Also works perfectly in Oracle APEX 5.1 to create `Classic Report` tables with static content, if completed with `FROM dual` after each `SELECT`, values and before `UNION ALL` if present.

Answer (score 158):

In `PostgreSQL`, you can do:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        VALUES
        (1, 2),
        (3, 4)
        ) AS q (col1, col2)
```

In other systems, just use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT  1 AS col1, 2 AS col2
-- FROM    dual
-- uncomment the line above if in Oracle
UNION ALL
SELECT  3 AS col1, 3 AS col2
-- FROM    dual
-- uncomment the line above if in Oracle
```

In `Oracle`, `SQL Server` and `PostgreSQL`, you also can generate recordsets of arbitrary number of rows (providable with an external variable):

```
SELECT  level
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
        level <= :n
```

in `Oracle`,

```
WITH    q (l) AS
        (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  l + 1
        FROM    q
        WHERE   l < @n
        )
SELECT  l
FROM    q
-- OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
-- uncomment line above if @n >= 100
```

in `SQL Server`,

```
SELECT  l
FROM    generate_series(1, $n) l
```

in `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: +1 for answering the (slightly different) question I had: how to do `SELECT 1` in Oracle (`SELECT 1 FROM Dual` worked).

Answer (score 25):

For Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL you may want to try this syntax

`SELECT constants FROM (VALUES ('foo@gmail.com'), ('bar@gmail.com'), ('baz@gmail.com')) AS MyTable(constants)`

You can also view an SQL Fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/34703/0

Comment: This absolutely works in SQL server 2010.  Multiple columns too:  SELECT constants,email FROM (VALUES (1,'foo@gmail.com'), (2,'bar@gmail.com'), (3, 'baz@gmail.com')) AS MyTable(constants,email)

Comment: How do you name the columns?  I've got  for example `'foo@gmail.com' AS email` but I get the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'`

Comment: @Michael would help if you had the full query

Answer (score 22):

The following bare `VALUES` command works for me in PostgreSQL:

```
VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)
```

Comment: Works in T-SQL as a multi-row insert clause, too. Inserting into a table variable or temporary table first could work, but multiple steps.

Answer (score 15):

Oracle.
Thanks to this post [PL/SQL - Use "List" Variable in Where In Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231757/pl-sql-use-list-variable-in-where-in-clause)

I put together my example statement to easily manually input values (being reused in testing an application by testers):

```
WITH prods AS (
    SELECT column_value AS prods_code 
    FROM TABLE(
        sys.odcivarchar2list(
            'prod1', 
            'prod2'
        )
    )
)
SELECT * FROM prods
```

Comment: This was a life saver. One thing to note: If you have run into a too many values error, you can just do a UNION ALL in the WITH clause.

Answer (score 13):

Try the connect by clause in oracle, something like this

```
select level,level+1,level+2 from dual connect by level <=3;
```

For more information on connect by clause follow this link : removed URL because oraclebin site is now malicious.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * 
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 9;
```

Comment: I was searching that hack for ages !!! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6):

Here a way to create custom rows directly with MySQL request `SELECT` :

```
SELECT ALL *
FROM (
    VALUES
        ROW (1, 2, 3),
        ROW (4, 5, 6),
        ROW (7, 8, 9)
) AS dummy (c1, c2, c3)
```

Gives us a table `dummy` :

```
c1   c2   c3
-------------
 1    2    3
 4    5    6
 7    8    9
```

Tested with `MySQL 8`

Comment: Nice mate, for MySQL, that's the way to go (also MySQL 8)

Comment: If you remove the `ROW` keyword, it works for SQL Server: `SELECT ALL * FROM (
VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)) AS dummy (c1, c2, c3);`

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I populate static data in Oracle 10+ using a neat XML trick.

```
create table prop
(ID NUMBER,
 NAME varchar2(10),
 VAL varchar2(10),
 CREATED timestamp,
 CONSTRAINT PK_PROP PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

merge into Prop p
using (
select 
  extractValue(value(r), '/R/ID') ID,
  extractValue(value(r), '/R/NAME') NAME,
  extractValue(value(r), '/R/VAL') VAL
from
(select xmltype('
<ROWSET>
   <R><ID>1</ID><NAME>key1</NAME><VAL>value1</VAL></R>
   <R><ID>2</ID><NAME>key2</NAME><VAL>value2</VAL></R>
   <R><ID>3</ID><NAME>key3</NAME><VAL>value3</VAL></R>
</ROWSET>
') xml from dual) input,
 table(xmlsequence(input.xml.extract('/ROWSET/R'))) r
) p_new
on (p.ID = p_new.ID)
when not matched then
insert
(ID, NAME, VAL, CREATED)
values
( p_new.ID, p_new.NAME, p_new.VAL, SYSTIMESTAMP );
```

The merge only inserts the rows that are missing in the original table, which is convenient
if you want to rerun your insert script.

Answer (score 3):

An option for DB2:

```
SELECT 101 AS C1, 102 AS C2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
SELECT 201 AS C1, 202 AS C2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
SELECT 301 AS C1, 302 AS C2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can do: `values (1,2), (3, 4);`

```
mysql> values (1,2), (3, 4);
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
2 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

With MySQL 8, it is also possible to give the column names:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4) AS dt (a, b, c, d);
+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: what version of mysql are you on for "values (1,2), (3, 4);"?

Comment: Is that second example actually still selecting multiple rows? Also neither of them seem to be runnable as queries in PhpMyAdmin.. I wish I could tell you which version of MySQL I am on, but MySQL versions are so confusing, and I'm sure by the time I figure it out, I will be out of time to edit this comment...

Comment: @ReneWooller don't know about op, but `VALUES` works for me on MariaDB 10.5.12

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle SQL you can use `JSON_TABLE` to create table from JSON:

```
SELECT
   t.emp_name,
   t.emp_age
FROM
   JSON_TABLE (
   '{
     "employees": [{name:"Alice", age: 19}, {name: "Bob", age: 23}]
  }',
  '$'
  COLUMNS (
     NESTED PATH '$.employees[*]'
     COLUMNS (
        emp_name VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.name',
        emp_age NUMBER(3,0) PATH '$.age'
     )
  )
) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN level = 1
    THEN 'HI'
    WHEN level = 2
    THEN 'BYE'
  END TEST
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 2;
```

Comment: `SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN level = 1  THEN 'HI'
    WHEN level = 2  THEN 'BYE'
  END field_desc,
  level as seq_code
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 3;`
better what you mean when you do it like this. but thanks this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

With SQLite3, the following select Go .QueryContext()

```
VALUES (1), (2)
```

Returns a single untyped column named **“Column1”**
and two rows with values 1 and 2

**VALUES** is a special form of the simple **SELECT** statement
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simpleselect

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using the XML features of DB2

```
SELECT *
FROM
XMLTABLE ('$doc/ROWSET/ROW' PASSING XMLPARSE ( DOCUMENT '
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <A val="1" /> <B val="2" /> <C val="3" />
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <A val="4" /> <B val="5" /> <C val="6" />
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <A val="7" /> <B val="8" /> <C val="9" />
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>
') AS "doc"
   COLUMNS 
      "A" INT PATH 'A/@val',
      "B" INT PATH 'B/@val',
      "C" INT PATH 'C/@val'
) 
AS X
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This way can help you

```
SELECT   TOP 3
         1 AS First, 
         2 AS Second, 
         3 AS Third 
FROM     Any_Table_In_Your_DataBase
```

`Any_Table_In_Your_DataBase:` any table which contains more than 3 records, or use any system table. Here we have no concern with data of that table.

You can bring variations in result set by concatenating a column with First, Second and Third columns from `Any_Table_In_Your_DataBase` table.

Comment: You should specify which database you use.  'TOP' keyword does not work with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (level - 1) * row_dif + 1 as a, (level - 1) * row_dif + 2 as b, (level - 1) * row_dif + 3 as c
    from dual 
    connect by level <= number_of_rows;
```

something like that

```
select (level - 1) * 3 + 1 as a, (level - 1) * 3 + 2 as b, (level - 1) * 3 + 3 as c
    from dual 
    connect by level <= 3;
```