# MySQL batch update statement with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Is there any *single* SQL statement equivalent to these?

```
UPDATE table_name SET (a = 'something', b='B1') WHERE id=1;
UPDATE table_name SET (a = 'something else', b='B2') WHERE id=2;
UPDATE table_name SET (a = 'another', b='B3') WHERE id=3;
```

Comment: What's wrong with executing three separate statements? Unless you're seeing particularly high latency to your server, this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET a = CASE WHEN id = 1
                THEN 'something'
                WHEN id = 2
                THEN 'something else'
                WHEN id = 3
                THEN 'another'
           END
 WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
;
```

but I'm not sure if it's what you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks, what about multiple fields (see edited question), can we wrap fields within CASE block or do we need to write different CASE blocks for each field? My query is going to update 5 fields. Thanks again.

Comment: The OP also wants to update b, you will need a second `CASE` for that.

Comment: You would need 5 `CASE` statements for your 5 fields.

Comment: @MoeSweet: You'll need separate CASE expressions, since MySQL doesn't support the `SET (a, b) = (...)` syntax *and* doesn't support CASE expressions that return multiple values.

Answer (score 2):

If you have bigger array of data to be inserted, then you may use [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) construction. It will work more efficient in MySQL.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35727615/4354249) for the similar question, for the example of usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select rows with your constant value, then join it with you table.

```
UPDATE table_name T INNER JOIN (select 1 as id,'something' as a,'B1' as b
union all select 2,'something','B2'
union all select 3,'another','B2') V on T.id = V.id set T.a = V.a, T.b = V.b;
```

Refer to [How to select multiple rows filled with constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2201170/6521116)