# Bulk update mysql with where statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update, bulk

How to update mysql data in bulk ?
How to define something like this :

```
UPDATE `table` 
WHERE `column1` = somevalues
SET  `column2` = othervalues
```

with somevalues like :

```
VALUES
    ('160009'),
    ('160010'),
    ('160011');
```

and othervalues :

```
VALUES
    ('val1'),
    ('val2'),
    ('val3');
```

maybe it's impossible with mysql ?
a php script ?

Comment: Put your pairs in a lookup table and join through that to create your update.

Comment: have you checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960569/mysql-bulk-insert-via-php

Comment: it can be done by MySQL, without involving of PHP. Check out my answer below, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The easiest solution in your case is to use [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) construction. It works really fast, and does the job in easy way.

```
INSERT into `table` (id, fruit)
    VALUES (1, 'apple'), (2, 'orange'), (3, 'peach')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fruit = VALUES(fruit);
```

or to use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) construction

```
UPDATE table
SET column2 = (CASE column1 WHEN 1 THEN 'val1'
                 WHEN 2 THEN 'val2'
                 WHEN 3 THEN 'val3'
         END)
WHERE column1 IN(1, 2 ,3);
```

Comment: Is this safe to use even when the column `fruit` is not unique? I'm confused by the statement in the mysql docs: "If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs" in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.

Comment: @swdon, the question you asked contradicts to the basic knowledge of MySQL. PRIMARY KEYs are UNIQUE. Table's [primary key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_primary_key) by definition is a unique key.

Comment: Sorry, I actually mixed up. In my case primary key is an auto incremented value and the update statement was checking for some other column that is neither primary key nor unique. But I got what you meant in the original answer.

Comment: This "ON DUPLICATE KEY" looks like a good technique, but note (no mysql) if any of the field in the table has no default value, it will fail to execute. So you have to push some placeholder value to pass this restriction, which decrease the portability of this solution.

Comment: Be careful with "ON DUPLICATE KEY" statements in MySQL, they will cause your auto_increment column to increase even if you're not inserting a new row. You can burn through A LOT of auto_increment values very quickly, if you are bulk updating with "ON DUPLICATE KEY". Make sure your auto_increment field is big enough to allow for this.

Comment: This seems very slow in large table.  But in my experience, updates by transaction was fast. e.g. start transaction;update1;update 2;... commit;

Comment: @JeffKilbride I don't understand why you said "they will cause your auto_increment column to increase even if you're not inserting a new row". I made a test,  inserted a record after I did a batch update by using "ON DUPLICATE KEY" statements, and found the the id is right after the last id(eg: if last id is 1000, the new record's id is 1001), I didn't found auto_increment column increased.

Comment: MySQL first increments the auto_increment field, then checks for duplicate values. If you use "ON DUPLICATE KEY", it can lead to gaps in your auto_increment field. See this answer for more info:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23517191/5605726. But, honestly, I don't know if this still applies to MySQL 8+. It's just something I'm always careful about.

Comment: I have seen big problems with deadlocks as well using this method. (on mysql 5.6 and 5.7) so I would probably avoid it if you have high concurrency

Answer (score 13):

If the "bulk" data you have is dynamic and is coming from PHP (you did tag it, after all), then the query would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (id, bar)
VALUES 
    (1, 'pineapple'),
    (2, 'asian pear'),
    (5, 'peach')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bar = VALUES(bar);
```

and the PHP to generate this from an existing array (assuming the array is of a format like:

```
$array = (
    somevalues_key => othervalues_value
);
```

) would look something like this (by no means the best (doesn't address escaping or sanitizing the values, for instance), just an quick example):

```
$pairs = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $pairs[] = "($key, '$value')";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `foo` (id, bar) VALUES " . implode(', ', $pairs) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bar = VALUES(bar)";
```

Comment: Davis, When i run the top statement you wrote it works in a table where there is only id and bar columns. But if the table contains more than id and bar, such as id,bar,date it doesnt work.

Do you have to specify each column even if it doesnt need updating ?

Comment: @Bonxy, in that case your query should modify as following, it did work for me. INSERT INTO `foo` (id, bar, date)
VALUES 
    (1, 'pineapple', d1),
    (2, 'asian pear', d2),
    (5, 'peach', d3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bar = VALUES(bar), date=values(date);

Answer (score 2):

You could try an UPDATE with JOIN as below:

```sql
UPDATE table
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 1 column1, 2 column2, 10 new_v1, 20 new_v2, 30 new_v3
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 column1, 5 column2, 40 new_v1, 50 new_v2, 60 new_v3
) updates
  ON table.column1 = updates.column1
  AND table.column2 = updates.column2
SET
  table.column1 = updates.new_v1,
  table.column2 = updates.new_v2,
  table.column3 = updates.new_v3;
```

As long as you can craft the inner `SELECT` statements from the `updates` subquery you would get the benefit of running all these updates in a single statement (which should give you some performance boost on InnoDB depending on your table size).

Comment: Although this looked to be a cleaner SQL solution than the `CASE WHEN THEN` answer, I ran into charset/collation complexities as the temporary `INNER JOIN (SELECT...)` table won’t automatically be the same as the parent table leading to “incorrect string value” errors with utf8mb4 values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a drag & drop tableView or collectionView to sort datas in your app, like allowing users to arrange their photos by drag and drop functionality, send a comma seperated list of ordered ids to the backend after user edits finish.

In your backend, explode ids to the an array like

```
$new_ranks = array();
$supplied_orders = explode(",", $_POST["supplied_new_order"]); //52,11,6,54,2 etc
$start_order = 99999;
foreach ($supplied_orders as $supplied_row_id) {
    //your all validations... make sure supplied_row_id belongs to that user or not etc..

    $new_ranks[intval($supplied_row_id)] = $start_order--;
}
```

now, you can update all new ranks like @Farside recommendation 2.

```
if (count($new_ranks) > 0) {
    $case_sqls = array(); 
    foreach ($new_ranks as $id => $rank) {
        $case_sqls[] = "WHEN ".intval($id)." THEN ".intval($rank)."";
    } 
    $case_sql = implode(" ", $case_sqls);

    $this->db->query("
        UPDATE 
            service_user_medias
        SET 
            rank = (CASE id ".$case_sql." END)
        WHERE 
            id IN(".implode(",", array_keys($new_ranks)).");
    ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `foo` (`id`, `bar`) VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b');
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `foo_tmp` LIKE `foo`;
INSERT INTO `foo_tmp` (`id`, `bar`) VALUES (1, 'c'), (2, 'd');
UPDATE `foo` f INNER JOIN foo_tmp ft ON f.id = ft.id SET f.bar = ft.bar;
```

Answer (score -7):

If you have data in array format then try this

and your query is like `"UPDATE table WHERE column1 = ? SET  column2 = ?"`

then set it like below

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $query->bind_param('ss', $key, $value);
    $query->execute();
}
```

hope it'll work.

Reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960569/mysql-bulk-insert-via-php).

Comment: you may remove your answer to get back your rating