# How to optimize an update query for multiple rows using MySQL and PHP

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has around 80.000 records. It has 4 columns:

```
|   id   |  code  |  size |  qty |  
+--------+--------+-------+------+
|    1   |  4735  |   M   |   5  |
|    2   |  8452  |   L   |   2  |
    ...
| 81456  |  9145  |   XS  |   13 |
```

The `code` column is unique.

I have to update the `qty` twice a day.

For that i'm using this query:

```
UPDATE stock SET qty = CASE id 
                         WHEN 1 THEN 10
                         WHEN 2 THEN 8
                         ...
                         WHEN 2500 THEN 20
                       END
              WHERE id IN (1,2,...,2500);
```

I am splitting the query to update `2500` stocks at a time using `PHP`.

Here is (in seconds) how much it takes for each `2500` stocks to update:

```
[0]7.11
[1]11.30
[2]19.86
[3]27.01
[4]36.25
[5]44.21
[6]51.44
[7]61.03
[8]71.53
[9]81.14
[10]89.12
[11]99.99
[12]111.46
[13]121.86
[14]131.19
[15]136.94
[END]137
```

As you can see it takes between 5 - 9 seconds to update 2500 products which i think is quiet a lot.

What can i change to speed things up?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried just generating a separate UPDATE statement for each row?

Comment: no it s actually quite normal, and how often do you want to do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk update mysql with where statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726910/bulk-update-mysql-with-where-statement)

Comment: @ADyson yes, it takes around 800 seconds using a different query for each record.

Comment: your query needs max 3,6 milliseconds per update,tow that is very fast

Comment: @emrhzc thank you but i can't use `on duplicate update` because there are some records that i don't need from the xml from which i'm taking the stock

Comment: what does that mean "some records that i don't need from the xml from which i'm taking the stock" ? sounds another task php needs to do just like preparing those values

Comment: other than that it's pretty identical in terms of functionality

Comment: @emrhzc Insert means that it will first try to insert a record. I'm taking the data for my stocks from an XML file generated by a third party. But that XML file containes products (codes) that i don't sell. Therefore using `Insert...ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` won't do the work for me here.

Comment: it will not insert if the index already exists, that's the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the times seem to be getting longer the further along you get, I'd expect you need an index on the id field, as it looks suspiciously like it's doing a full table scan.  You can create the index something like this

```
CREATE INDEX my_first_index ON table(id);
```

(I am having to add this as an answer because I can't make comments, I know it is more of a comment!!)

** EDIT **

I re-read and see your issue is bigger.  I still think there is a chance that putting an index on id would fix it but a better solution would be to have a new table for the id to quantity mappings, lets call it qty_mapping

```
|   id   |  qty |  
+--------+------+
|    1   |   10 |
|    2   |   8  |
    ...
| 2500   |   20 |
```

make sure to index id and then you can change your update to

```
update stock set qty = (select qm.qty from qty_mapping qm where qm.id = stock.id)
```

It should be able to update the whole 80,000 records in next to no time.

Comment: can you please be more explicit about what `qty_mapping` is? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Melody - If you look at your code, you are doing a massive case statement near the top to set the quantity based on the id.  If you look at my answer, you'll see I've put the pairs you show in your example into my example of the database output.  If you put each of these many thousads of values pairs into the database, you don't need the massive case statement, the sub query does it for you.

Comment: Wow! Ok so i tried this and here is the result: after creating the `qty_mapping` table and indexing both tables `code` column the total update time was reduced from `137 seconds` to `3 seconds`. Thank you so much!