Optimizing bulk updates in MySQL for a table: performance issues with 10,000 rows
Consider the following that is designed to contain up to 10000 rows :
CREATE TABLE T(
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    weight MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

Every 6 hours I need to update the weight of each row from freshier data. I narrow this number down by comparing beforehand the values that remain the same between the table and the freshier data, but the worst case is still 10000 rows to update. The fresh data simply consists of a map id->value. So here I'm not talking about UPDATE T SET weight = {value}; because I need to set each row's field to a specific value.
Initially I had thought that a single query should be faster so I was regrouping all updates in an INSERT INTO T(id, weight) VALUES ({id_1}, {weight_1}), ..., ({id_n}, {weight_n}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = VALUES(weight); statement which was kind of fast (even though I don't remember exactly how fast it was) but I quickly found out that my AUTO_INCREMENT id was incrementing even when the row was updated and not inserted, which it's very wrong in my case because the data type of the id itself (SMALLINT UNSIGNED) was chosen because it was the one with the lowest maximum value (32767) greater than the maximum theorical number of rows of the table (10000). I could use BIGINT UNSIGNED but since I only update this table it seems like a waste of space and a very lazy way to fix the problem.
I just tried making an UPDATE T SET weight = {value} WHERE id = {id}; query for each id->value pair but it is painfully slow as it takes around 600ms for all the queries to complete.
I also just tried to regroup all id->value pairs in a single UPDATE T SET weight = CASE id WHEN {id_1} THEN {weight_1} ... WHEN {id_n} THEN {weight_n} END WHERE id IN ({id_1}, ..., {id_n}); statement but it still takes around 600ms to complete.
You might tell me that 600ms every 6 hours is not that much and I would agree FOR THIS TABLE, but I will have similar cases to deal with on a way more regular basis where this high delay will for sure be an issue.

The best way to do this is to put all the new values in a temporary table. Then update the original table using UPDATE original_table JOIN temp_table ...

@Barmar I was trying this when I came back to put that as the answer : it now takes around 60ms to complete (10 times less) which is good. Thank you.

@Bill Karwin I read on a comment on the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726910/bulk-update-mysql-with-where-statement that IODKU statements will cause the AUTO_INCREMENT id to increase even if no new row inserted.

@Bill Karwin Also I simplified the table for this problem but in reality the data isn't just made of a weight. I was not providing the id when using the IODKU statement because it's not included in the freshier data, but the other fields are. I put a UNIQUE constraint on them and those are the ones used in the IODKU statement.

you could avoid the "comparing beforehand the values that remain the same" and just use a new table: create table T2 like T; insert into T2 ....; rename table T to T_old, T2 to T; drop table T_old.  Since you are only running this a few times a day, and yet were concerned about a 600ms time, seems like the goal is to avoid even pretty short locks, the rename table is the best way to do this, even if the insert takes longer than updating with a join

huh, IODKU does seem to needlessly bump the auto_increment, when the dup is not on the auto_increment key, never knew that

@ysth as IODKU starts with insert and when that fails proceeds with the update, it is actually logical that it increments auto increment value.

It may be fastest to build a new table, then swap tables:
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
INSERT INTO new 
    SELECT ...   -- including `real.id`
        FROM real
        JOIN updates ON ...
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;

If the incoming data may add new rows (hence, creating new ids), I would suggest two queries in place of that one INSERT -- one to deal with updated rows, another to add new rows (cf LEFT JOIN).
(The Question is too vague for me to spell out the full details.)
