# SELECT on an array of constants

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, how is it possible to do a `SELECT` on an array of constant values? Something similar to this:

> SELECT ['1', '2', '3'] AS ID;

Where the desired output is:

```
+-----+
| ID  |
+-----+
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
```

Comment: Have you considered using `UNION`s?

Comment: I would like to do this with ~20 values, so if there is a solution that is simpler than a tower of `UNION`s, would use that :)

Comment: Have you searched through SO? [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201170/how-to-select-multiple-rows-filled-with-constants)

Comment: And what is the purpose of that?

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili I want to use those values later for `JOIN`s. I know I can just use a temporary table, but I am curious if such a syntax exists for MySQL.

Comment: No you can't do it with easy line of codes, but can be done with procedures. don't you use any other programming lang? for generating JSON? or directly from mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use joins to generate a series of rows.

```
SELECT 1 AS ID UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
```

For small amounts of data this works well. Down side is that there is no index to check these on.

A temp table is likely far better for this as at least any SQL that joins against these values can then use indexes.

Another possibility if the values are from a limited pool is to just have a table which contains all possible values and select from it:-

```
SELECT ID 
FROM all_poss_values
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

or using a generated range of values (which again loses the availability of indexes):-

```
SELECT 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 AS ID
FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
(SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
WHERE 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 IN (1,2,3)
```