# PL/SQL - Use "List" Variable in Where In Clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

In PL/SQL, how do I declare variable MyListOfValues that contains multiple values (MyValue1, MyValue2, etc.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseTable 
WHERE DatabaseTable.Field in MyListOfValues
```

I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't do that (at least not in Oracle 11). I suggest that you build a dynamic query and execute that. Best of luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a large number of strings to match with oracle database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699223/how-to-load-a-large-number-of-strings-to-match-with-oracle-database)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a collection:

```
CREATE TYPE Varchar2TableType AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
```

Or use a built-in type like `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` or `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`:

```
VARIABLE cursor REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  your_collection SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
BEGIN
  your_collection.EXTEND( 100 );

  your_collection(  1) := 'Some value';
  your_collection(  2) := 'Some other value';
  -- ...
  your_collection(100) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'x', 20 );

  OPEN :cursor FOR
  SELECT t.*
  FROM   your_table t
         INNER JOIN
         TABLE( your_collection ) c
         ON t.id = c.COLUMN_VALUE;
END;
/

PRINT cursor;
```

Comment: Works; thx.  How can I also return the row count?  I am getting a value of 0 though data exists in the cursor.

Comment: Are you using a procedure/function or an anonymous PL/SQL block?

Comment: Anonymous PL/SQL block. Thx

Answer (score 8):

Create the SQL type like this:

```
CREATE TYPE MyListOfValuesType AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

And then use it in a SQL statement

```
DECLARE
  MyListOfValues MyListOfValuesType;
BEGIN
  MyListOfValues := MyListOfValuesType('MyValue1', 'MyValue2');

  FOR rec IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM DatabaseTable
    WHERE DatabaseTable.Field in (
      SELECT * FROM TABLE(MyListOfValues)
    )
  )
  LOOP
    ...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Up until Oracle 11g, this only works with a SQL `TABLE` type, not with a PL/SQL `TABLE` type. With Oracle 12c, you could also use PL/SQL types.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a WITH clause which basically builds a temp table?  Not real reusable.  You could use an array or I would argue joining to a lookup table would be better.

```
WITH MyListOfValues(col1) AS (
  select 'MyValue1' from dual union
  select 'MyValue2' from dual union
  select 'MyValue3' from dual 
)
SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseTable  
WHERE Column in (
  select col1
  from  MyListOfValues);
```

Comment: This requires only the privileges for the query, the other solution creates a type.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT     REGEXP_SUBSTR ('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) pivot_char
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

I got this from:

https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1639911