# How to pass multiple values to UPDATE or SELECT COUNT(*) statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to do a update a record.

Table name is customer

```
id | name    | address         | state
---+---------+------------+-------------------------
 1 |    John | 123 main st     | TX
 2 |    Jack | 678 John st     | NJ
 3 |    Bet  | 987 Tx st        | NY
 4 |    Maddy| 9812 Hudson st | CA
 5 |    ABCD | 9813 Mainly st  | PA
```

My query is like below

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER c SET c.state = 'CA' WHERE c.id IN (idList);
```

Where idList is a localVariable that I created and it returns a list of id like 1,3,5

The query is working if do it like

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER c SET c.state = 'CA' WHERE c.id IN (1,3,5);
```

It is updating the respective records to CA.

But if I use it as

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER c SET c.state = 'CA' WHERE c.id IN (idList);
```

I get the below error. I don't want to pass the list directly as the list might change. I am getting the list of ids using a different command where it returns and assigns to idList as 1,3,5

Error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   ORA-06512: at line 35
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"**

How to solve this? I am writing it as a stored procedure.

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare and assign idList?

Comment: Would look like this as a example

```
Select s.ID_LIST into idList from CUSTOMERDETAILS.ID s where s.FILTER_STATE = ‘CA_STATE’;
```

O/P would be like 

```
ID_LIST
1,3,5
```

Comment: If I do DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IDList values' || idList);

I am able to see the list that is generated 1,3,5 .

But not sure what is going wrong if I pass idList in query it is not working but working if I pass the numbers directly

Comment: What type is `idlist` of?

Comment: idList VARCHAR2(500 BYTE);

Comment: You can either use TYPE or WITH clause. Please take a look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231757/pl-sql-use-list-variable-in-where-in-clause. Hope that can help you.

Comment: If the column in the table is also a string and stores a comma separated list of IDs, you really should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) and fix that schema.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `idList`  is a comma separated string with all the `id`s that you want to update.
So what is happening is that the operator `IN` compares each `id` with that string and since this comparison can't succeed in any case you get an error.

What you can do instead is use the `LIKE` operator:

```
UPDATE customer
SET "state" = 'CA'
WHERE ',' || idList || ',' LIKE '%,' || "id" || ',%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=02843c2be3a85dab899193f89d9b73d6).

Answer (score 0):

You may create parameterized query string and pass values like,

UPDATE CUSTOMER c SET c.state = 'CA' WHERE c.id IN (:idList);

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple values. As the data for IdList will be huge don't wanna pass one num at a time for 1 run.

Comment: I thought you are passing values from java. Read all ids using cursor and loop over it and use single value for update query. Run the procedure it will update all ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can't substitute a text variable for a list of values - it's simply not allowed. You're going to have to use dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE CUSTOMER c SET c.state = ''CA'' WHERE c.id IN (' || idList || ')';
```