# Is there a way to accept comma separated input in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to confirm if it's acceptable to provide a comma separated input through a prompt in PLSQL query. For example the input to be like order_no = 12345;67890;09876

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
select order_no
from CUSTOMER_ORDER_JOIN
where order_no like nvl('&Order_no', '%')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PL/SQL - Use "List" Variable in Where In Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231757/pl-sql-use-list-variable-in-where-in-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, no, you can't do that because Oracle considers string you enter as a *whole*. For example, this query returns nothing because there's no job whose name is `Clerk,Manager` (both values).

```
SQL> with emp (ename, job) as
  2    (select 'Smith', 'Clerk'    from dual union all
  3     select 'Allen', 'Salesman' from dual union all
  4     select 'Ward' , 'Salesman' from dual union all
  5     select 'Jones', 'Manager'  from dual
  6    )
  7  select ename, job
  8  from emp
  9  where job in ('&par_jobs');
Enter value for par_jobs: Clerk,Manager

no rows selected

SQL>
```

**However**, if you have Apex installed in your database, and that Apex version supports `apex_string.split` function, then you can do something which is close to what you're looking for:

```
SQL> with emp (ename, job) as
  2    (select 'Smith', 'Clerk'    from dual union all
  3     select 'Allen', 'Salesman' from dual union all
  4     select 'Ward' , 'Salesman' from dual union all
  5     select 'Jones', 'Manager'  from dual
  6    )
  7  select ename, job
  8  from emp
  9  where job in (select * from table(apex_string.split('&par_jobs', ',')));
Enter value for par_jobs: Clerk,Manager

ENAME JOB
----- --------
Smith Clerk
Jones Manager

SQL>
```

**Otherwise**, you'll have to type a little bit more to achieve that, e.g.

```
SQL> with emp (ename, job) as
  2    (select 'Smith', 'Clerk'    from dual union all
  3     select 'Allen', 'Salesman' from dual union all
  4     select 'Ward' , 'Salesman' from dual union all
  5     select 'Jones', 'Manager'  from dual
  6    )
  7  select ename, job
  8  from emp
  9  where job in (select regexp_substr('&&par_jobs', '[^,]+', 1, level)
 10                from dual
 11                connect by level <= regexp_count('&&par_jobs', ',') + 1
 12               );
Enter value for par_jobs: Clerk,Manager

ENAME JOB
----- --------
Smith Clerk
Jones Manager

SQL>
```

---

Basically, YMMV.