# Alternative option to UNION ALL

Tags: sql, db2, union, union-all

I have the SQL below:

```
SELECT '1.1' AS column_a, '1' as column_b, 4 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '1.2' AS column_a, '1' as column_b, 4001 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.1' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 1 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.1' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 2 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.1' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 3 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 1001 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 1002 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 1003 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 1004 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 1005 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 1006 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 2001 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 2002 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 2003 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.2' AS column_a, '2' as column_b, 2004 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '3.1' AS column_a, '3' as column_b, 3001 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '3.1' AS column_a, '3' as column_b, 3002 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '3.2' AS column_a, '3' as column_b, 3003 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT '3.2' AS column_a, '3' as column_b, 3004 AS column_c FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

The SQL result is fixed, all the values will be the same.

I am using DB2. Is there a better way to do the same thing without so many duplication in SQL?

Comment: you can use VALUES, like `VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 2)`

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?

Comment: How do I check the version of DB2?

Comment: I get result "DSN10015" when I execute SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

Comment: Check DB2 version: `select * from SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS`

Comment: When I execute "select * from SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS" I get error: "SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS IS AN UNDEFINED NAME"

Comment: Oops. That was for iSeries, the LUW flavor is `SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select multiple rows filled with constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201170/how-to-select-multiple-rows-filled-with-constants)

Comment: He is using db2 10 for zOS

Answer (score 1):

As Lashane commented, VALUES might be the answer if your platform and version of DB2 support it.

This works on DB2 for i v7.1

```
with tbl (col1,col2) 
  as (VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 2))
select * from tbl
```

Comment: I believe my version of DB2 does not support it. I get the error: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "TBL". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: DSN_INLINE_OPT_HINT

Comment: @Daniel you are using db2 10 for zOS your version supports it you just need the correct syntax.

Comment: @daniel -- see my answer.

Comment: No, the `VALUES` usage here does not work on DB2/zOS. You must use `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` with `UNION` or use the `XMLTABLE` technique below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PureXML` to parse an embedded XML block into a table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM XMLTABLE (
'/set/row'
PASSING XMLPARSE(
'<set>
<row a="1.1" b="1" c="4"/>
<row a="1.2" b="1" c="4001"/>
<row a="2.1" b="2" c="1"/>
</set>')
COLUMNS
column_a CHAR(3) PATH '@a',
column_b CHAR(1) PATH '@b',
column_c INTEGER PATH '@c'
) AS X
```